# How to post image on Imgur via OAuth

Tags: iphone, ios, oauth, imgur

Im working on an iPhone app in which i've to post image to user's Imgur account.
Can any one tell me how to post image in Imgur account via `OAuth` authentication.
I am new in IOS and have very little knowledge about OAuth.
Till now I can't even find the suitable OAuth library for iPhone ios.

Comment: [This OAuth library](https://github.com/H2CO3/MPOAuthiOS) is quite good.